# Selecting rows from one grid & passing them to another grid

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm trying to allow rows to be selected via checkboxes and for those selected rows and their IDs to be sent to another grid when a 'Submit' button is clicked. In other words, acting as some sort of filter.

I've contacted Telerik's support team and was advised to take the following steps in order to get it working:

1. Get the selected rows with the *Select()* method of the Grid
2. Loop through them & get the underlying item with the *dataItem* method
3. Save them into an array
4. Destroy the grid
5. Initialize a new grid by setting the *data data*

Here's a sample on [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ILejOdip/13) that shows what I have in mind.

I'm not sure where to start honestly. I would really appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction to any resources or guides that would be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using RadGrid, make sure you have client side selection turned on, you would see something like this:

```
   <ClientSettings>
       <Selecting AllowRowSelect="True" />
       <ClientEvents OnRowSelected="RowSelected" />
    </ClientSettings>
```

On the input button, make sure to call your JS method as follows :

```
  <input onclick="GetSelected();" .... >
```

Your JS code might look something like this :

```
  function GetSelected() {
      var grid = $find("<%=Your Grid's ClientID Here%>");
      var MasterTable = grid.get_masterTableView();
      var selectedRows = MasterTable.get_selectedItems();  // 1. Get the selected rows. The selected item can be accessed by calling the get_selectedItems() method of the GridTableView client-side object. 
      for (var i = 0; i < selectedRows.length; i++) {
        var row = selectedRows[i];
     // This is where you would have to insert it in a collection so that you can bind it to another grid... You will need to call .Rebind() once you assign the new datasource to the other grid.
      }
```

Hopefully this will give you some idea.. I can see if I can find any examples on inserting rows into other grid if you get stuck.

Comment: I'm using the grid in Kendo UI Web actually. Thanks for that though.

Comment: In that case the syntax would be different. Something like this probably... 



    var myGrid = $("#MyGrid").data("kendoGrid");
    var rows = myGrid.select();
    rows.each(function(index, row) {
          var selectedItem = myGrid.dataItem(row);
          // you can have something like otherGrid.insert(...); 
        });

Answer (score 0):

check this code

html

```
<div id="grid1"></div>      
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="Move()" />
<div id="grid2" ></div>
```

script

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            var data1 = [
         { id: 1, rating: 3, year: 1997, title: "Rock" }
        , { id: 2, rating: 5, year: 1999, title: "X-Man" }
        , { id: 3, rating: 4, year: 2011, title: "World War Z" }
    ];

            var grid1=$("#grid1").kendoGrid({
                sortable: true
                        , silectable: true
                        , selectable: "multiple row"
                        , filterable: true 
                        , pageable: true
                        , columns: [
                        { template: "<input type='checkbox' class='checkbox' />", width: "40px" }
                         ,{ field: "id", title: "Id", filterable: false }
                       , { field: "rating", title: "Rating", filterable: false }
                      , { field: "year", title: "Year", filterable: true, type: "string"}
                      , { field: "title", title: "Title" }
                        ]
                       , dataSource: { page: 1,
                           pageSize: 5,
                           data: data1
                       }

                   }).data("kendoGrid");
                   grid1.table.on("click", ".checkbox", selectRow);

            var data2 = [
         { id: 101, rating: 6, year: 2012, title: "The Impossible" }
        , { id: 102, rating: 8, year: 2013, title: "Escape" }
        , { id: 103, rating: 7, year: 2013, title: "Gravity" }
    ];
            $("#grid2").kendoGrid({
                sortable: true
                        , silectable: true
                        , selectable: "multiple row"
                        , filterable: true 
                        , pageable: true
                        , columns: [
                         { field: "id", title: "Id", filterable: false }
                       , { field: "rating", title: "Rating", filterable: false }
                      , { field: "year", title: "Year", filterable: true, type: "string"} 
                      , { field: "title", title: "Title" }
                        ]
                       , dataSource: { page: 1,
                           pageSize: 5,
                           data: data2
                       }

            });

        });

        function Move() {
            var grid1 = $("#grid1").data("kendoGrid");
            var rows = grid1.select();

            rows.each(function(index, row) {
                var selectedRow = grid1.dataItem(row);
                //-move to grid2
                var grid2 = $("#grid2").data("kendoGrid");
                var ins = { id: selectedRow.id, rating: selectedRow.rating, year: selectedRow.year, title: selectedRow.title }; //id=1,rating=9.2,year=1995,title="The Godfather"
                grid2.dataSource.insert(ins);
            });

            rows.each(function() {
                grid1.removeRow($(this).closest('tr'));
            });
        }

        function selectRow() {
            var checked = this.checked,
                row = $(this).closest("tr");
            if (checked) {
                //-select the row
                row.addClass("k-state-selected");

            } else {
                //-remove selection
                row.removeClass("k-state-selected");
            }
        }  
    </script>
```

this will help you :)

Comment: Thanks so much, has certainly pointed me in the right direction. I keep getting a `Cannot call method 'value' of undefined` error though when adapting it to my own code. Not sure why.